# Bind a dropdownlist inside the Layout View

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, view, partial

I am an ASP.NET WebForms programmer and I'm very new to ASP.NET MVC3. I've got a dropdownlist inside the _Layout view and it needs to be populated on all the pages. I don't want to have to call some code inside every Controller, so I've moved the dropdownlist in a Partial View and put it on the page using @Html.Partial("_DropDownList"). Do I need to create a controller for this View? If so, how can I specify control it needs to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to look at [@Html.Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.childactionextensions.action%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) and [@Html.RenderAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.childactionextensions.renderaction%28v=vs.98%29.aspx). They allow you to reference a controller action and return the output.